# set dynamic property value in sun-web.xml

Tags: glassfish, jvm, environment-variables

I set JVM environment variable in `domain.xml`:

```xml
<jvm-options>-Dmydir=c:/mydir</jvm-options>
```

I am making virtual drive for my application and I want to set the value of the `alternatedocroot` property to take **jvm environment variable** .
Any help please .

for example:

```xml
<property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/images/* dir=${mydir}" />
```

Comment: Depends on build tool. Maven can do that.

Comment: this value of alternatedocroot will be changed dynamic at runtime before lunching the app server . And after deploying the application
this property should be read by the application @BalusC

Comment: Yes, I understood that. Did you understand my comment?

Comment: no ,I don't understood your comment , can you please give me an example how maven can do that . @BalusC

Comment: I'm not that versed with Maven that I could answer that from top of head. But if you're not already using Maven, then perhaps you need a different solution. At least, there's nothing which JSF as being a simple MVC framework can do for you here, so I removed the irrelevant JSF tag.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC for your help. In web.xml i can use el, is their any restriction in sun-web.xml about using el.